# How to Match Number greater than 50 Before specific char with Regex

Tags: regex

I have this string:

```
50 C/114F
```

50[space char]C

I want some regex to find the number before " c" in the string and select if greater than 49.

Sorry for my bad English.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this pattern: `^([5-9]\d|[1-9]\d{2,})(?=\sC)`

See [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Jfsm7N/2)

**Explanation**

- `^` start of the line.
- `[5-9]\d` if the number is two digits then the first digit must be between 5-9 and the second can be anything from 0-9.
- `[1-9]\d{2,}` if the number is more than two digits then the first digit must be between 1-9 and for the other two or more digits, it can be anything between 0-9.
- `(?=\sC)` Check that after the match is a white-space and C character? if so then match the previous pattern and if not it does not match.

Comment: You could put a `0*` after the first open parenthesis and another one after the vertical bar to allow leading zeroes in the numbers.